# Host binding when .net core deployed as a windows service

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, host

We have a web API that we have created using .NET core 2.1. We have two servers which sit behind a netscaler load balancer. Inside these servers, we managed to install our web APIs in port 5000. Now we have a DNS hostname which mapped to our load balancer. How can we do hostname binding for our windows service? If we deploy using IIS then there we can specify this binding, but when deployed as a windows service how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use UseUrls extensions method on IWebHostBuilder and use special way of binding to the urls: **http://+:5000**. With this binding the application will try to bind to http://localhost:5000 as well as http://{hostname}:5000.
So the code in your case would be:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseUrls("http://+:5000");
```

You have to ensure that the account running the windows service have appropriate level of permissions to bind to the network path!

EDIT:

As @Lex Li mentioned in comments, this last part about permissions is not completely correct, as you can reserve the use of URL during the installation process. When done in this manner, the account running the Windows service does not have to have elevated permissions. 
[Details](https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#reserved-urls)

Comment: "You have to ensure that the account running the windows service have appropriate level of permissions to bind to the network path". Not really. When installing such a Windows service, the installer can reserve that URL, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#reserved-urls and then the service might run under a less privileged account.